# Present a specific tab in a tabbar modally with storyboard

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, modal-dialog

I have a login screen, and after auth, I have a tab bar controller with navigation controllers for each views, which I want to present.

[image]

Here is the code I use

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *obj=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Problem is The tab bar is not showing. Also, how can I specify to show the second view in the tabbar controller if I needed to?

I am using storyboard.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `pushViewController`, do a `[self presentViewController:(UIViewController *) animated:(BOOL) completion:^(void)completion]`

This will show the new view controller as full screen.

You can also create a named segue from the login screen to the tab controller with a modal transition style. You could then call `[self perfromSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR SEGUE NAME" sender:nil];`

To load the 2nd tab in the tab bar, you can do

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]
```

to select the 2nd tab.

Comment: I tried it, but still the tab bar is not showing. I am new to ios, and I should confess I am not well versed with obj c. Do you think I am not initializing the tab bar controller correctly? please see code section in post.

Comment: Ok got it. overlooked something in the storyboard. Thanks